# Prove that $\langle , \rangle$ is an inner product iff $A$ is a positive definite, symmetrix matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

[image: #3]

I'm sorry, I don't even know where to start. (Also, I'm not very good at formatting, so bear with the screenshot).

Comment: Do you know the definition of an inner product?

Comment: satisfies properties of linearity, symmetry, and is pos def

Comment: Show that $<,>$ so defined satisfies each of the axioms of an inner product. Eg show $<x,y>=\dots =<y,x>$ etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, suppose that $\langle,\rangle$ is an inner product. Then, $\langle x,y \rangle = \langle y,x\rangle$ for all vectors $x$ and $y$. So, $x’Ay=y’Ax$ for all $x,y$. Take $x=e_i$ ($1$ at $i$-th position and $0$ elsewhere) and $y=e_j$ in the above equation, whence you will get that $A_{ij} =A_{ji}$ , showing that $A$ is symmetric. Now, $\langle,\rangle$ being an inner product, $\langle x,x \rangle \geq 0$ and equality holds iff $x=0$, so $x’Ax \geq 0 $ and equality holds iff $x=0$, showing that $A$ is p.d.. 
Now, suppose that $A$ is symmetric, p.d.. Then, as suggested in the comments above, just verify each axiom of an inner product. For example, $\langle x,y\rangle =\langle y,x\rangle$ follows from $A$ is symmetric, $\langle x,x \rangle > 0$ for all non-zero $x$ follows from $A$ is p.d., and linearity follows from elementary linearity properties of matrix multiplications. You must try out these routine jobs in order to understand things!

Answer (score 0):

If $A \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$ is p.s.d. we can always find a $L \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$ such that $A = L^TL$ (from eigen decomposition and assumpted $A$ is full rank)

From your definition, $<x,y> = x^TAy$, by plugging in our decomposition we have

\begin{equation}
<x,y> = (xL)^T(Ly)
\end{equation}

Thus your operation $<,>$ is just an inner product after a linear mapping $L:\mathbb{R}^{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{N}$